# Checking Powers of Four - Edge Case

Tags: python, algorithm

***Disclosure:*** This question is from [codewars](http://www.codewars.com).

> Write a method that returns true if a given parameter is a power of 4, and false if it's not. If parameter is not an Integer (eg String, Array) method should return false as well.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what edge case I'm missing. Both code samples produce the same error that 'True should equal False' for some test. (I tried it two ways when the first didn't work, since I was positive the second would.)

```
def powerof4(n):
    if n <= 0 or not isinstance(n, int): return False
    else:
        while (n != 1):
            if (n%4 != 0): return False
            else: n = n/4
        return True
```

and

```
import math
def powerof4(n):
    if ((not isinstance(n, int)) or n&(n-1) != 0 or n == 0):
        return False

    #Now, I cheat, since 4^n = (2^n)^2
    reduce_to_2 = math.sqrt(n)

    if math.floor(reduce_to_2) != reduce_to_2:
        return False
    else:
        reduce_to_2 = int(reduce_to_2)
        return reduce_to_2&(reduce_to_2 - 1) == 0
```

Comment: One possibility is that `1` as `4^0` is an invalid solution, i.e., the powers of 4 go like 4, 16, 64 and so on. But for deducing this is the case, you will need to add the complete question verbatim to the post.

Comment: @mu無 Unfortunately (for this question), 4^0 is a valid solution. I have posted the entire question verbatim above.

Comment: is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Python 2.7

Comment: The first algorithm does not work on Python 2.7, and the second times out

Comment: @AnttiHaapala They both work on my local machine with 2.7.2

Comment: @New Starting with `4^16` and higher powers they return `false`

Comment: I appreciate the informative answers (which have been very enlightening), but I'm looking for an edge case that comes back True when it should be False.

Comment: @New If you print the value at codewars at which the test feails you see it's for the call  `powerof4(True)`. `isinstance(True, (int,long))` is `True` because bool is a subclass of `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are checking if the type of the argument is `int` but starting with numbers larger than 2^32 thats not true for Python 2 which codewars is using.

The next error is if you print the value at codewars at which the test fails you see it's for the call  `powerof4(True)`. `isinstance(True, (int,long))` is `True` because bool is a subclass of `int`.

In your first code change your typecheck to

```
if n <= 0 or type(n) not in (int,long): return False
```

---

To add another variation on the problem. When I solved this problem initially some time ago I did it with some bit fiddling :)

```
def powerof4(n):
    if type(n) not in (int, long):
        return False
    bin_repr = bin(n)[2:]
    return bin_repr[0]=="1" and bin_repr.count("0")%2==0 and bin_repr.count("1")==1
```

Comment: or `isinstance(n, (int, long))`

Comment: But Numbers will pass the condition for float also, right?

Comment: @AdamSmith Or remove the type check at all

Comment: I didn't realize that was the case for ints, however, my error suggests that some test is coming back True when it should be False. The initial check is more to ensure something is not an int rather than it is (list, dict, string, etc..)

Comment: @halex Good call. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `bin_repr = bin(n)[2:]` is better written as `bin_rep = format(n, 'b')`

Comment: @JonClements Is your version better because it's more readable, because timing both versions they are nearly the same: `python -m timeit "format(123456, 'b')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.741 usec per loop` and `python -m timeit "bin(123456)[2:]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.398 usec per loop`

Answer (score 1):

There is one less obvious gotcha. In Python 2 the number could be too big to fit in an `int` and it would be a `long` instead:

```
>>> isinstance(1000000000000000000000000000000, int)
False
```

whereas Python 3 would return

```
>>> isinstance(1000000000000000000000000000000, int)
True
```

---

The *easiest* algorithm on any CPython (*except for the `isinstance` check) could be

```
def powerof4(n):
    if n <= 0 or not isinstance(n, (int, long)):
        return False
    return hex(n).rstrip('0') in ('0x1', '0x4')
```

This converts the number into hex, and removes trailing zeroes; a number is a power of 4 if and only if the hex representation is 1 or 4 followed by any number of zeroes. (hint: it would be a power of 16 if it were 1 followed by zeroes).

---

With bitwise logic:

```
test = 1
while n < test:
    test <<= 2
return n == test
```

---

In Python 2.7 and 3.3+ this is even easier, no loop needed:

```
b = n.bit_length()
return bool(b & 1) and 1 << (b - 1) == n
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way.

```
import math

def powerof4(n):
    return math.log(n, 4) % 1 == 0
```

Comment: Yes. I initially didn't want to use library functions. Also, this misses some checks, namely `return isinstance(n, (int, long)) and n > 0 and math.log(n,4) % 1 == 0`. I like the simplicity though :)

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to propose - might be worth a `try: ... except (TypeError, ValueError): return False` though - `TypeError` will catch anything that's not a number, and `ValueError` will catch where `n == 0`

Comment: @JonClements personally I'd rather let the exception bubble up if the caller tries to find out if `"64"` is a power of 4! :)

Comment: @Adam indeed... but the the function should return True/False... so that's the responsibility of the function to handle the exceptions... not the caller (but anyway... a bit moot as the main gotcha is that `True` won't raise exceptions, so an explicit check still needs to be made similar to halex's answer

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
def isPowerOf4(n):
    try:
        while n:
            if n==1:
                return True
            if ((n>>2)<<2) != n:
                return False
            n >>= 2
    except:
        return False
    return False
```